# how to send an IRB to background using Java?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I have an IRB and I want to send it to background and evaluate IRB's commands using Java.
I tried something like this [1], but it doesn't recognize any commands.

[1]

```
String response = "";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(myIrb); //myIrb is a unix script which starts the IRB

try {
  pb.command(myCommand);
  Process proc = pb.start();
  InputStream input = proc.getInputStream();
  int i;
  while((i = input.read()) != -1) {
    char c = (char)i;
    response += c;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    response = e.toString();
  }

System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: make sure when you write to the process, you send it a carriage return or it might not get your data

Answer (score 0):

If you want the thing to execute in the background, then you don't want to execute the *Ruby* script directly, you want to invoke a *shell* to execute the Ruby script.

For Windows, use "start".  For Linux, use "&".

Comment: I want to send the IRB to background using Java . (I have a class which extends HttpServlet so the IRB will remain alive during the http session). The problem is that I don't know how to evaluate the commands.

Comment: To "execute in the background", you'll need to do what I suggested.  Or wrap it in a .bat file (Windows) or shell script (Linux).  To "evaluate the commands", you can do what you're doing (read the process's "stdout" with "proc.getInputStream()".  Alternatively, you could also create a pipe, open a socket, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you want to evaluate ruby in a seperate IRB process rather than evaluating it directly from java?

http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/RedBridge

This would be a lot simpler.